# Powershell - Pass multiple parameters to Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'm trying to write a one-liner to leverage some of the capabilities of netbackup remotely. I know how to pass parameters to Invoke Command using -args[0] and [1] at the end, with repeating parameters. An example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

CC = Country Code (Will repeat due to the naming conventions

SS = Site (Also repeats due to naming convention)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer -ScriptBlock {& "C:\Program Files\Veritas\NetBackup\bin\admincmd\bpplinfo.exe" CC0SITE_VMW_BRON -set -L -M CC0SITEb0100d0a.s0SITE.CC.DOMAIN.COM}
```

After getting user-input and declaring the parameters, it doesn't seem to pass to the invoke-command

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer -ScriptBlock {& "C:\Program Files\Veritas\NetBackup\bin\admincmd\bpplinfo.exe" $args[0]0$args[1]_VMW_BRON -L -M $args[0]0$args[1]b0100d0a.s0$args[1].$args[0].DOMAIN.com} -Args $CCode, $Site
```

Answer (score 12):

Use *param($val1,...)* inside the scriptblock to pass the arguments.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'SERVERNAME' -ScriptBlock {
param($argument1, $argument2) #<--- this is required!
 write-host $CCode
 write-host $Site
} -ArgumentList ($argument1, $argument2)
```

More information and syntax can be found at ArgumentList (alias Args) section for [Invoke-Command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an issue with the way you're expanding your variables and hence it may appear the args are not being passed correctly, when I'm debugging I simply use *write* to test the output. For example:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {write "C:\Program Files\Veritas\NetBackup\bin\admincmd\bpplinfo.exe CC0SITE_VMW_BRON -set -L -M CC0SITEb0100d0a.s0SITE.CC.DOMAIN.com"}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {write "C:\Program Files\Veritas\NetBackup\bin\admincmd\bpplinfo.exe $($args[0])0$($args[1])_VMW_BRON -set -L -M $($args[0])0$($args[1])b0100d0a.s0$($args[1]).$($args[0]).DOMAIN.com"} -Args "CC", "SITE"
```